# Find the number of $k$ satisfying $\frac{n}{3} - 1 < k \leq \frac{n}{2}$ for $n > 9$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that the number of $k \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $\frac{n}{3} - 1 < k \leq \frac{n}{2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n> 9$ is greater than $\frac{n}{6}$.

I looked at the distance $|\frac{n}{3} - 1 - (\frac{n}{2})| = 1 + \frac{n}{6}$ which is $> \frac{n}{6}.$ Is this correct or am I missing a proper justification? I'm not sure how to use the $n > 9$ fact either. Thank you.

Comment: You need to be careful with using the distance, as you did, in terms of the boundary conditions with the required inequalities and the value of $k$ being an integer. Although the total is $\gt \frac{n}{6}$, it's possible for there to be fewer than that integers which satisfy the inequalities. Regarding using $n \gt 9$, as I show in my answer, doesn't seem to really be needed, so I'm not sure why it's provided. As I state in my answer, perhaps there's another required condition that is not included here.

Comment: There were not any additional conditions provided so I was a bit dumbfounded myself. Thank you for your response, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = 6m + r$ for some non-negative integer $m$ and integer $0 \le r \le 5$. Thus, the question asks to prove there are more than $\frac{n}{6} = m + \frac{r}{6} \lt m + 1$ values of $k$, i.e., that there are at least $m + 1$ such values.

The inequality becomes

$$2m + \frac{r}{3} - 1 \lt k \le 3m + \frac{r}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

In general for large divisors, you would normally look at various spans of values of $r$. However, since there aren't too many here, you can instead fairly easily manually check the results of the $6$ possible values of $r$ to get:

$$r = 0 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m - 1 \lt k \le 3m \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$r = 1 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m - \frac{2}{3} \lt k \le 3m + \frac{1}{2}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
$$r = 2 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m - \frac{1}{3} \lt k \le 3m + 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
$$r = 3 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m \lt k \le 3m + \frac{3}{2} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$
$$r = 4 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m + \frac{1}{3} \lt k \le 3m + 2 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$
$$r = 5 \; \Rightarrow \; 2m + \frac{2}{3} \lt k \le 3m + \frac{5}{2} \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

With \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3}, $k$ goes from $2m$ to $3m$ inclusive, so there are $m + 1$ values which work. Similarly with \eqref{eq4}, $k$ goes from $2m$ to $3m + 1$, so there are actually $m + 2$ values which work. With \eqref{eq5}, $k$ goes from $2m + 1$ to $3m + 1$, for $m + 1$ values. Finally, \eqref{eq6} & \eqref{eq7} give $k$ going from $2m + 1$ to $3m + 2$, for $m + 2$ values.

As such, this works for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, including for $n \gt 9$. I'm not sure why this restriction is used in the question. Are there perhaps any other unstated conditions?